# How can I implement a fixed position search bar in android 2.2?

Tags: android, search, android-layout

I'm trying to write a simple wikipedia app for Android 2.2 which allows users to search and view articles.

When a user is viewing an article, I'd like there to be a fixed position search bar that remains fixed at the top of the screen, despite the vertical scroll position, as in this picture: 
http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/9159/wikidroid01.png

How can I implement that search bar? Is it a view I stick in my layout? I've already read about Search Dialog boxes in this android tutorial (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)... but it's my understanding that the search dialog box search bar can only show if it is focused (when onSearchRequested() is run), right?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by taking relative layout of fixed height. In that relative layout add the elements in order that you have shown in picture like 
1) Imageview with wrap_content height & width.
2) Take Editext with fixed height & width also set Hint for that EditText="Search WikiPedia".

Put this layout as first element in your main layout so that it will be always at top if vertical scroll is there it will  not scroll that search bar.

Comment: So the search bar is something I have to style myself? Like the search button image and the gradient? Is there some way to easily create a search bar that looks the same as the search bar in a Search Dialog?

Comment: i have used the search functionality in this manner which i told u. It works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html). They allow you to have 2 (or more) views that are controlled separately. Read more [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html).

Fragments are new to Android 3.0 however there is a [compatibility pack](http://oscandy.com/fragments-for-all/) that allows you to use them as early as Android 1.6.